# requests.get() not retrieving correct url in python 2.7

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to access url and then parse it's contents based on tags.
My code:

```
page = requests.get('https://support.apple.com/downloads/')
self.tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
names = self.tree.xpath("//span[@class='truncate_name']//text()")
```

Problem: variable page is containing data that of url `'https://support.apple.com/'`
I'm new to python 2.7. The whole encoding issues in file. I'm using `unicode-escape` as my default encoding. Encoding on resource at `https://support.apple.com/downloads/` is `utf-8` whereas encoding of resource at `https://support.apple.com/` is variable. Is this has something to do with the problem? Please suggest solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with encoding , what you are looking for is dynamically created so not in the source you get back.  A series of ajax calls populates the data. To get the product names etc.. from the carousel where you see the `span.truncate_name` in  your browser:

```
params = {"page": "products",
          "locale": "en_US",
          "doctype": "DOWNLOADS",
          }
js = requests.get("https://km.support.apple.com/kb/index", params=params).content
```

Normally we could call *.json()* on the response object but in this case  we need to use  `"unicode_escape"` then call *loads*:

```
from json import loads, dumps
js2 = loads(js.decode("unicode_escape"))
print(js2)
```

Which gives you a huge dict of data like:

```
{u'products': [{u'name': u'Servers and Enterprise', u'urlpath': u'serversandenterprise', u'order': u'', u'products': .............
```

You can see the request in chrome tools:

[image]

We leave off `callback:ACDow‌​nloadSearch.customCa‌​llBack` as we want to get back valid json.

Comment: probably you are picking up params from url `https://km.support.apple.com/kb/index?page=mainproducts&locale=en_US&doctype=DOWNLOADS&pagetype=DOWNLOADS&callback=ACDownloadSearch.customCallBack`. Is value for `page` in `params` a typo? This question can be naive. I just want to understand, new to this. :)

Comment: @pslover, I monitored the requests in chrome tools, you can see the params passed in the image above, add back in `callback:ACDow‌​nloadSearch.customCa‌​llBack` and just print the content and you will see why I left it out